# Wordpress body_class();

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to echo a custom post type or taxonomy type in a div that works similar to body_class(); ?

I 'd like to ***ECHO CUSTOM TAXONMY OF POST OBJECT BEING QUERIED***

```
<div class="sideBarForms">
        <?php 

$posts = get_field('forms');

if( $posts ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <div class="***ECHO CUSTOM TAXONMY OF POST OBJECT BEING QUERIED***"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: I think WordPress has this function already, you can see the source code of this site: freenish.com. Fox example: one post's class are 'post-838 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-wordpress-themes tag-black-theme tag-responsive-theme tag-slider-theme tag-two-column'.

Comment: You may want `post_class` (might not work outside a bonafide Loop) or `get_post_class` (you can specify a post ID). That will get you the output @aisin mentioned.

Comment: SO none of these work since I need a taxonomy...